# How can I assign a variable's value to another variable which comes before?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

My code is here :

```
$array_letter = array("A","B","C","Ç","D","E","F","G","H","I","İ","J","K","L",
                      "M","N","O","P","R","S","Ş","T","U","Ü","V","Y","Z");

$sql = "SELECT id,city  FROM city WHERE city LIKE '" .$array_letter[$i]."%'";
```

And after these codes :

```
for ($i=0;$i<27;$i++) {
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

 echo "<h3>".$row['city']."</h3>";

   }    
}
```

$sql is meaningless because `$array_letter[$i]`will not work there. But $sql must be top of these codes for design. Because I coded `switch-case statement`. According to requests, `$sql` will change for this reason I can not write `$sql` under for loops. But all my queries depens on `$array_letter`. How can I make `$array_letter` work?

Comment: do you want us to predict $i for you ;-)

Comment: No, I don't. While for loop works, how can $i be assigned in $sql? That is what I want.

Comment: Cool letters btw, is that Turkish? :)

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `mysqli` driver and prepared statements:

```
$st = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,city FROM city WHERE city LIKE ?'");
for ($i=0;$i<27;$i++) {
  $st->bind_param("s", $array_letter[$i].'%');
  $st->execute();
  $result = $st->get_result();

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<h3>".$row['city']."</h3>";
  }  
}
```

Although for this case, I would recommend just doing one big query since it looks like you are getting everything: `SELECT id,city FROM city ORDER BY city`...

For educational purposes, an alternative approach would be to do something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar='%s'";
mysql_query(sprintf($sql, "42"));
```

That can be useful in other situations, but again, if you are writing SQL, use prepared statements as they solve this problem more gracefully with the extra protection of helping to prevent SQL injection attacks and minimizing the amount of SQL parsing the server has to do.

Comment: *Almost everything*, the original queries ignored all NULLs and strings beginning with symbols not in the array. But one large query is still the right way to go, IMO.

Comment: @Dcoder, a valid point, but if the database has garbage, it should be cleaned up. Also, adding a check for `!= NULL` would satisfy the one potentially legitimate concern. (I would guess there is code not shown that displays headers per letter, which is still easily done with one big query.)

Answer (score 1):

You should use prepared statements, as Matthew mentioned in his answer.

Otherwise consider this (using PHP 5.3 closures):

```
$sql = function($i) use ($array_letters) {
    return "SELECT id,city  FROM city WHERE city LIKE '" .$array_letter[$i]."%'";
}
```

Then inside your loop:

```
mysql_query($sql($i));
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. This code  was  the thing that I searched.

Comment: @kalaba2003 you're welcome. I do urge you to investigate in PDO / mysqli prepared statements, it's really nice to use :)

Answer (score 0):

This will help to reduce the database calls.

```
$array_letter = array("A","B","C","Ç","D","E","F","G","H","I","İ","J","K","L",
                  "M","N","O","P","R","S","Ş","T","U","Ü","V","Y","Z");
for($i=0;$i<count($array_letter);$i++){
if($i!=count($array_letter)-1)
$qstring.="city like '".$array_letter[$i]."%' or ";
 else
$qstring.="city like '".$array_letter[$i]."%'";
}
$sql = "SELECT id,city  FROM city WHERE ".$qstring;
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<h3>".$row['city']."</h3>";
  }
```